# How to get paramaters in controller function action in Zend 2?

Tags: redirect, zend-framework2, parameter-passing

this is my code:

```
 public function registerAction(){
                    $this->redirect()->toRoute(null, array(
                        'controller' => 'user',
                        'action' =>  'confirm',
                        'param1' =>'email',//$request->getPost('mail'),
                        'param2'=>$request->getPost('name')
                    ));
  }
   public function confirmAction(){
        $params = $this->params()->fromRoute('param1');
        var_dump($params); exit();
        return new ViewModel();
    }
```

and this is the code from the config:

```
.....
'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '[:controller[/:action]][/:param1][/:param2]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'action' => 'index',
                                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
....
```

I am  trying to send 2 parameters in a redirect, to receive in the confirmAction function and send it tot view. But i get in the var_dump always the **null** value. I tried all of this:

```
$this->params()->fromPost('paramname');   // From POST
$this->params()->fromQuery('paramname');  // From GET
$this->params()->fromRoute('paramname');  // From RouteMatch
$this->params()->fromHeader('paramname'); // From header
$this->params()->fromFiles('paramname');  // From file being uploaded
```

but with no result. Can anyone help me with this ? thx

Answer (score 0):

you have to set in the config the parameter name, which is in my case : **param1**

```
'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '[:controller[/:action]][/:param1]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'action' => 'index',
                                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                                'param1' => 'tralala'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
```

After that in the controller when you do a redirect:

```
 public function registerAction(){
     $this->redirect()->toRoute(null, array(
                        'controller' => 'user',
                        'action' =>  'confirm',
                        'param1' =>'my_email'
                    ));
}
  public function confirmAction(){
        $params = $this->params()->fromRoute('param1');
        var_dump($params); exit();
        return new ViewModel();
    }
```

You will receive the **my_email** string